# Compare passwords if hashed using random salt with sha512?

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, sha, password-hash

I think there is a contradiction about the recommendations how to store password in database.
We hash the password and store it in DB, and when a user tries login, we hash his input string the same way and compare to the DB. that's fine.
But there are recommendations to strengthen that hash by adding a random salt.
here is the problem:
So we lose the whole point of comparison, because the salt values will be different between the first hash to store in DB and the salt when login??
If to store in Db the salt, so what is the benefit is salting at all?

Comment: Also see OWASP's [Secure Password Storage](https://www.google.com/search?q=owasp+secure+password+storage). John Stevens did a really nice job of creating the threat models and placing security controls to contain the threats. It includes the reason for salting a password.

Comment: *"If to store in Db the salt, so what is the benefit is salting at all?"* - Salting ensures two users who happen to select the same password don't collide in the database. Without it, a user could use his password to probe for other user's passwords (assuming he/she had a way to dump the user table). Upon a hit, he/she could spoof as a different user because he learned the password.

Comment: @jww - Getting different hashes for equal passwords is only a minor benefit of salting, the actual reason is to prevent rainbowtable attacks.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - A single salt for the entire table will provide the protection against precomputation. See ATTACK 1.2 in the threat model detailed at [Secure Password Storage](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R6c9NW6wtoEoT3CS4UVmthw1a6Ex6TGSBaEqDay5U7g/edit#heading=h.3emqhab5wr1p).

Comment: @jww - That's true and it is not related to collisions. Precomputation means that you cannot calculate the rainbowtable before you know the global salt, but you **can** build 1 rainbowtable to get all passwords. Unique salts negate the advantage of rainbowtables at all. I wrote a small tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php), maybe you are interested.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - That's not how the attacks work in real life. The attacker simply picks a "Top N Password" list, and systematically tries them. As far as I know, attackers don't build those tables. Even recovery attempts for the big breaches like Adobe were based on the Top N list. You can find a collection of Top N Password lists for N=100, N=10,000, N=1M, N=10M at Daniel Miessler's [SecLists | Passwords](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords). Also see Peter Gutmann's book [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf), Chapter 7.

Comment: @jww - That's true again, but it is not the purpose of the salt to prevent dictionary attacks. To mitigate dictionary attacks you need key-stretching, password-hash functions with a cost factor to control the necessary time for a single hash calculation. Salting and key-stretching are two different countermeasures, both are important.

Answer (score 7):

You also store the salt. Comparison is between stored hash value and `HASH(salt + input)`. The purpose of the salt is to prevent two users that use the same password to generate the same hash.

Comment: isn't stoing the salt insecure, because we are talking about a hacker whho will get the password from the database, so along with the salt, it will be easy to crack the password. what am I missing?

Comment: no, is not insecure. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt

Comment: The *salt* is considered public information, whose only purpose is to make each hash unique and prevent brute force attacke which are based on precalculated values (like rainbow tables)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why we generate a random salt for each password is, that one cannot build a single rainbowtable to get all passwords at once. Instead an attacker has to build a rainbowtable for each salt/password. Building a rainbowtable to get a single password is pointless, because you can stop searching if you found a match.

In other words, salting prevents the usage of rainbowtables. This purpose is fulfilled even if the salt is known, one still has to build a rainbowtable per password, that's why we can store the salt together with the hash in the database.

Btw: The SHA-* hash functions are not appropriate to hash passwords, instead one should use a password-hash function like BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2 or Argon2. They all have a cost factor to make hashing slow.

**Edit**

Following examples are only for better understanding, the salt should not be added this way:

```
1. Example with the same (global) salt for all passwords:

hash("Password1"+"o9*eiwrC49YAS2395%tu") => hash1
hash("Password2"+"o9*eiwrC49YAS2395%tu") => hash2
hash("Password3"+"o9*eiwrC49YAS2395%tu") => hash3
```

To find out Password1, we can build 1 lookup table with all reasonable passwords and the global salt. To find out Password2 we can reuse the same lookup table, because all passwords use the same global salt.

```
2. Example with unique salts for each password:

hash("Password4"+"ierukElasidj42Swiekq") => hash4
hash("Password5"+"oeuoElwWPJckfk212344") => hash5
hash("Password6"+"PoiMnmdvhas98akd73lk") => hash6
```

To find out Password4 we would have to build 1 lookup table with all reasonable passwords and the salt `"ierukElasidj42Swiekq"`. To find out the Password5 one has to build another lookup table with the salt `"oeuoElwWPJckfk212344"` and so on. The first example required 1 lookup table, the second example requires as many lookup tables as passwords.

Comment: sorry, but didn't understand why if the salt is known it's not enough to build one lookup table for all passwords, it just hashing again the known salt with each guessed password , e.g                                                                                         salt + 'hello' = qtgyw0002                                                                                  salt + 'martin123' = j3j2ki2900

Comment: @DanielMoreshet - I added an example to make the difference between a global salt and a unique salt more clear.